# Within a view listing, how can I denote whether a node's date is upcoming, current or past?

Tags: views, datetime

I am working on an art gallery site in which we have two [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) that are filtered based on the date range of an exhibition. One view filters current exhibits (now >= start date && now <= end date) and another that filters upcoming exhibitions (now < start date).

We would like to combine these into a single page view. This is simple enough to do with this date filter: now <= end date. However, I would still like to denote which events are upcoming (be it a CSS class or by rendering the date field as "Opens on Dec. 12th").

**Is there a way to render/rewrite the date field differently based on the field's value relative to today's date?**

For example, if today's date is Nov. 1, 2015, I would like these two nodes:

- Exhibit #1 (Oct. 1, 2015 - Dec. 1, 2015)
- Exhibit #2 (Jan. 1, 2016 - Feb. 1, 2016)

To render like this:

- Exhibit #1, *Ends Dec. 1 2015*
- Exhibit #2, *Opens Jan 1, 2016*

Comment: I assume you are able to modify your theme? Also, are you using the "Unformatted list" style?

Comment: Actually, this will be outputting as a Masonry style dynamic layout (like Pinterest and google+ use). The issue here is more in getting the rewrite results to look at the date value and change the output based on that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Pierre's suggestion, I installed the "Views PHP" module. Here's how I set up my view:

1. Added my *date* field (field_dates) and then *Global: PHP* field
2. Make sure date field is "Excluded from Display"
3. Edit the "Output code" of the Global: PHP field to the following

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$start_date = strtotime($data->field_field_dates[0]['raw']['value']);
$end_date   = strtotime($data->field_field_dates[0]['raw']['value2']);
if  (time() < $start_date) {
   echo 'Starts on ';
   echo date("F j, Y", $start_date);
} else if (time() < $end_date) {
   echo 'Open Until ';
   echo date("F j, Y", $end_date);
} else  {
    echo 'Closed on ';
    echo date("F j, Y", $end_date);
}
?>
```

Note, `field_field_dates` is not a typo. That extra `field_` is required for the code to work. Using the values listed in my questions example, the results are:

- Exhibit #1, Open Until December 1, 2015
- Exhibit #2, Starts on January 1, 2016

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) feature "rewrite result" (as explained also in [Rewriting view fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/1578524)), combined with the [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module.

If you're not experienced in PHP, you may want to experiment with only the "rewrite result" feature, which may help to come up with an acceptable compromise for what you're looking for.;

**Note**: The [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module only has an alfa version as of today, but it's used in about 70K sites anyway ... That many sites can't be wrong, right?

Comment: I will look into this. Although I am not an experienced PHP programmer. Thanks.